# Adaptative width with flexbox and flex-grow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to set up a menu bar with the 
 [following template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTPpc.png)

I'm trying this with FlexBox but I can't figure out what's wrong. Here's the HTML :

```
<nav>
<ul>
            <li id="navleft">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo wikihow">
            </li>

            <li class="navothers">
                <img src="images/contribuye.png" alt="contribuye">
                <p>CONTRIBUYE</p>
            </li>   
            <li class="navothers">
                <img src="images/explora.png" alt="explora">
                <p>EXPLORA</p>
            </li>
            <li class="navothers">
                <img src="images/entrar.png" alt="entrar">
                <p>ENTRAR</p>
            </li>
            <li class="navothers"><img src="images/mensajes.png" alt="mensajes">
                <p>MENSAJES</p>
            </li>   
</ul>
</nav>
```

And I apply the following styles in CSS :

```
nav {
     padding: 0 30% 0 30%;
}

nav ul {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    background-color: #93B874;
}

#navleft{
    flex-grow:32;
    flex-shrink:1;
}

#navleft img{
    width: 144px;
    vertical-align:center
}

.navothers{
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-shrink:4;
}
```

I get the  [following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bUYc.png)

My problem is that all the elements in the right part (with the "navothers" class) dont have the same width ! They just adapt depending on the size of the text they have.

I may have mixed a lot of things, what have I done wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your flex-grow value for #navleft is too big, and your container is too small. Your items can't grow they don't have enough room. Try this :

**CSS :**

```
nav {
    padding: 0 10% 0 10%; // imho it's a strange way to center your nav. Reduced to show you that you're lacking room.
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #93B874;
}

#navleft {
    flex: 2; // You may tune this one but keep room for your other items !
}

#navleft img {
    width: 144px;
    vertical-align: center
}

.navothers {
    flex: 1;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="navleft">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo wikihow">
        </li>

        <li class="navothers">
            <img src="images/contribuye.png" alt="contribuye">
            <p>CONTRIBUYE</p>
        </li>
        <li class="navothers">
            <img src="images/explora.png" alt="explora">
            <p>EXPLORA</p>
        </li>
        <li class="navothers">
            <img src="images/entrar.png" alt="entrar">
            <p>ENTRAR</p>
        </li>
        <li class="navothers">
            <img src="images/mensajes.png" alt="mensajes">
            <p>MENSAJES</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/me7t2hv3/**

Comment: Thanks for the insight!

As LGSon stated, the main problem was because of the flex-basis attribute. In your example, you use the short version "flex: 1" which also sets a criteria "flex-basis:0"

Now concerning the way of centering the nav, what would be the best approach? I did that to test but what's wrong with it?

Comment: I would set a width and margin: auto;